# Good resources for learning event driven flash development?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, event-driven

What are good books / site where you can learn the best practices for event driven programming in actionscript (3 obviously).

I've got a big project coming up and, to be honest, my flash is usually a big mess of classes and I don't want the the next one to turn into a ball of hair behemoth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colin Moock's [Essential Actionscript 3.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526946) has a good explanation of events.

If you want free online stuff, here are some introductory articles on how AS3 Events work with the Display list:

- [Introduction to event handling in AS3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html)
- [Understanding the AS3 Event Flow](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/860/1/Understanding-the-AS3-Event-Flow/Page1.html)

[Using Event Dispatcher](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/204/1/Using-EventDispatcher/Page1.html) is for AS2/Flash MX 2004, but is a decent introduction to the *concepts* of events, event dispatchers, and event listeners.

Answer (score 1):

After buying ActionScript books I still use the Adobe PDF Manuals the most. They are free downloads:

From this site: http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flash/ you can get just about every Flash and ActionScript reference for Free, including:

Flash Tutorial:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/UsingFlash/flash_cs3_help.pdf

Programming Action Script:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/flash_as3_programming.pdf

Language and Component Ref Zip:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3.zip